# programmatically getting custom node belonging to a term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, database

have searched google but cannot find anything specific . Intention is to get all Custom Node types that have been assigned a specific term of vocabulary . for example the follwoing is a db query to get custom node type.

`$query->condition('type', "news_article")->fields('n',array('nid'))->orderBy('created', 'DESC')->range(0,90);`

can the same query be modified to also add the  filter for term id .

One other related question is that how can (in PHP) we get the term id from the url of the pattern e.g `<drupal site>/taxonomy/term/2` .

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the comments. Instead of using entity field query , have used the solution mentioned in the following question:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52334/know-the-term-id-get-all-the-node-id-belong-to-it?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful

[How to use EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.org/node/1343708)

It works great for me. As far as the other question is concern, there are many ways of doing this. the simplest would be below, provided that you are accessing link in your question:

```
<?php
    $arg0 = arg(0);
    $arg1 = arg(1);
    $arg2 = arg(2);

    echo $arg0; //this will echo 'taxonomy'
    echo $arg1; //this will echo 'term'
    echo $arg2; //this will echo 2 (term ID)
?>
```

Info about `arg()` can be found here: [arg()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7)

Comment: Thank you for the answer . will look and inform asap . thank you again :)

Comment: when I try `propertyCondition('tid', 4)` , it says that the property tid is unknow. kindly help in this

Comment: what is the machine name and filed type of the field that you use to assign term to a node? I would imagine you are doing so by using entity reference or term reference.
it should be more like 
->fieldCondition('field_machine_name', 'target_id', 4)

Comment: the vocabulary name is `field_category` and the term id is 4

Comment: would you mind showing your entity field query? -> fieldCondition above rather than -> propertyCondition should work.

Comment: `$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
                $query->entityCondition("entity_type", "node")
                ->propertyCondition("tid", 4);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use arg() function for getting tid, if you are panels then you can find it in $context.
Anyways I am assuming you are not using panels.
So, the code goes this way:-

```
$arg = arg();
$query = db_select('node','n');
$query->join('taxonomy_index','ti','n.nid=ti.nid');
$query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
  ->condition('n.type', 'your_content_type_machine_name')
  ->condition('ti.tid', $arg['2']);
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
//do dsm($result); if you have devel module enabled.
or you can use our traditional way. echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo "</pre>";
```

I think this query help you in getting associated nids of particular tid.